# Importerror when launchen jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I recently added some handy features for Nbextensions. So therefore I run the following code:

```
conda install  -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

This all worked fine. However when Im restarting a notebook now:

```
jupyter notebook
```

I get the following error:

```
Importerror: No module named bunch.
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here and how I can get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing module bunch with

```
$ pip install bunch
```

Comment: The problem still exists... Any other thoughts?

Comment: bunch is not a direct dependency for jupyter_contrib_nbextensions, so the fact it's showed up now may just be a coincidence, resulting from the fact the  nbextensions install asked you to restart the notebook server. My best bet is that multiple python distributions or virtualenvs are at work...